# Need help for apply style to button

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap and applying a custom theme to it. I have cut the corners on variations of my **.btn** class using the following css:

```css
.btn-primary {
  border:none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px,  rgb(0,130,114) 7px)
}
.btn-primary:hover, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:active {
  border:none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px,  rgb(0,106,91)  7px)
}

.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn.active.focus{
  outline:none;
  box-shadow:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px">
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4"> 
</div>
```

**This results in buttons looking like this:**

[image]

Which is exactly what I want, however when you click on a button it goes back to the original rectangular shape. I have tried the :active, :enabled and :focus pseudo classes but the rectangular shape still appears as in this picture.

[image]

What other pseudo classes or elements could be causing this and how can I resolve it.

Comment: Praveen Kumar's solution works, however you have to update it to target the specific class rather than just .btn. I have used: .btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active:focus ,
.btn-primary.active:focus,
.btn-primary.focus,
.btn-primary:active,
.btn-primary:active:hover,
.btn-primary.active.focus {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px,  rgb(0,106,91)  7px)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS is being overwritten by bootstrap for the ":active:focus" event.

Include this line of code (below). This will fix your issue.

```
.btn-primary:active:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px, rgb(0,106,91) 7px);
}
```

Cheers!!
Let me know if it worked.
I forked your code into my Codepen account and fixed the issue.
Here take a look:
http://codepen.io/thekamlesh/pen/ZpXgJY

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `background` as same as the one you have, and **do not use `!important`**:

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active,
.btn:active:hover,
.btn.active.focus{
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px,  rgb(0,106,91)  7px);
}
```

**Working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgXOwb**

Comment: Unfortunately I have already tried these and they did not work. You can try it yourself here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dpVBAX

Comment: @ObiEff Trying it... Behold. I had the same problem.

Comment: @ObiEff Works with Background.

Comment: @ObiEff Check updated answer. Don't use `!important`.

Comment: Yes this works, I had to change it to ,btn-primary and add the same thing for btn.default but it works good now. Thanks

Comment: K. Shrestha has provided an answer which narrows it down to the :active:focus pseudoclass. You're answer is still correct just this is more accurate. Thanks

Comment: @ObiEff Agreed. No issues. `:)`

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**

A Quick Fix add `!important` to background.

> !important is valid CSS. You might inherit a project wherein the
>   previous developers used it, or you might have to patch something up
>   quickly — so it could come in handy.

CSS:

```
.btn-primary {
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px, rgb(0, 130, 114) 7px)
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus,
.btn-primary:active {
  outline: none!important;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, transparent 7px, rgb(0, 106, 91) 7px)!important;
}
```

Comment: Already tried these and unfortunately did not work. Try the codepen I have added.

Comment: add `!important` to background. answer has been updated